# Is this Android Studio IDE break point twice trigger bug?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-studio-2.1

I'm playing with android `CoordinatorLayout` demo to figure out how the scroll behavior works.

I find that if I toggle the breakpoint in the `return line` --- the breakpoint will trigger twice(with same stacktrace, the log output is only once)

shows below:

[image]

but when I toggle the breakpoint at `Log line` --- it is just run as I expect.

[image]

It compiles with normal debug configuration, and didn't use `minifyEnabled` kind stuff, is it a bug of Android Studio 2.1.2? Or is it a limitation on JDWP?

---

As for now, I need to reminder myself don't trust the breakpoint at return clause, even in debug build case.